# Unwanted white space at bottom of bootstrap carousel slider in rails app?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I have some code for a landing page with 4 pictures that change via carousel:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 welcome d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" >
    <div class="welcome-slider">
      <div class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <div class="carousel-item active">
              <%= image_tag 'Eureka.jpg', class: 'd-block w-100' %>
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <%= image_tag 'pensive.jpg', class: 'd-block w-100' %>
          </div>


          <div class="carousel-item">
            <%= image_tag 'NYC.jpg', class: 'd-block w-100' %>
          </div>

          <div class="carousel-item">
            <%= image_tag 'Success.jpg', class: 'd-block w-100' %>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="comingsoon">
        <h1 class="font-white"> Coming soon </h1>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my coffeescript:
  landing.coffee

```
    $(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
      $('.carousel').carousel()
```

AND static_pages.coffee

```
$item = $('.carousel-item')
$wHeight = $(window).height()
$item.height $wHeight
$item.addClass 'full-screen'
$('.carousel img').each ->
  $src = $(this).attr('src')
  $color = $(this).attr('data-color')
  $(this).parent().css
    'background-image': 'url(' + $src + ')'
    'background-color': $color
  $(this).remove()
  return
$(window).on 'resize', ->
  $wHeight = $(window).height()
  $item.height $wHeight
  return
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.full-screen {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The coffeescript does not seem to affect the page at all, as the white space exists with or without it. Can anyone help advise on how to get rid of white space at bottom of page? Is any of this coffeescript necessary?